# Chamar janela modal dentro de código php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

eu tenho esta página de login abaixo e quero sempre que o submit for clicado e os inputs text estiverem vazios uma janela modal seja aberta quando o código de verificação do php for executado também.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin Area | Account Login</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>


    <script>

    </script>


  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Area Administrativa</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <header id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">Area Administrativa <small>Login de Agentes</small></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <form id="login" method="POST" class="well">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Agente Fiscalizador</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome de Angente" name="nome" id="nome">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="password" id="senha">

                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="log">Login</button>

              </form>


              <?php


              if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['password']))
              {
                $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                if(!empty($nome) && !empty($password))
                {
                  $funcoes->conectar("localhost", "sistema_de_reboques", "root", "");

                  if($funcoes->logar($nome, $password) == true)
                  {
                    header("Location:index.html");
                    echo "Entrou";
                  }
                  else
                  {

                    echo "<h5 align='center' >Agente ou Senha Errados!</h5>";
                  }


                }
                else
                {

                  ?>
                  <script>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function()
                      {
                         $("#log").click(function(e){

                        $("#mymodal").modal("toggle");

                        });
                      });

                </script>
                  </script>

                  <?php
                  echo "<h5 align='center' >Preencha os Campos Vazios!</h5>";
                }
              }

              ?>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>






    <footer id="footer">
      <p>Copyright Sistema de Reboques, &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>


    <!--Janela Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Necessário efetuar pagamento</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="pagar.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Pagar Agora</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




  <script>
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para abrir a modal vc usa `.modal('show')`.

Answer (score 0):

Como o Sam disse, para especificamente exibir um modal, você utiliza `$('seletor').modal('show')`. O `.modal('toggle')` provavelmente funcionaria nesse caso, mas o problema que vejo é que a biblioteca Javascript do Bootstrap está sendo incluída na página no final da página, de forma que esteja depois do código que você executa para exibir o modal.

Vejo duas saídas possíveis nesse caso:

- Mover a o carregamento do Javascript do Bootstrap para dentro da tag HEAD
- Mudar o código `$(function(){` para `$(document).load(function{`. Dessa forma, o script só seria executado após o carregamento completo da página, o que inclui o carregamento de todos os arquivos Javascript.